# .htaccess redirect not directing to specified file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have an .htaccess file on an old domain of mine that includes redirects that aren't redirecting as I am wanting.

If I type in olddomain.com/about-us.html the redirect is sending the user to newdomain.com/about-us.html. What I am trying to do is direct the user to newdomain.com/about.

Below is my .htaccess file with one example of the redirect.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/administrator [NC]

RewriteRule /about-us.html https://newdomain.com/about [L,R=301]

Redirect 301 /about-us.html  https://newdomain.com/about


RewriteRule ^ https://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Network Tab:

[image]

Comment: @anubhava Yes, I did clear it.

Comment: @anubhava Check my edit in my question. I posted an image of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^about-us\.html$ https://newdomain.com/about [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/administrator [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

- Make sure to test it in a new browser or completely clear browser cache.
- Make sure there is no other code in your .htaccess when you test

Comment: Thanks! This worked. For deeper files within sub-folders, would I do this? `RewriteRule /about-us/employees\.html$`

Comment: Don't use leading slash. So use: `RewriteRule ^about-us/employees\.html$ /something [L,R=301,NC]`

Comment: Am I doing it wrong? This specific line isn't working. I tried different browsers. `RewriteRule ^about-us/t-slotted-aluminum-profiles\.html$  https://newdomain.com/profile [L,R=301,NC]`

Comment: URL - `https://mbkitsystems.com/about-us/t-slotted-aluminum-profiles` . There is another htaccess in the new domain, but no redirects.

Comment: You rule is matching `.html` in the end so your source URL should be: `https://mbkitsystems.com/about-us/t-slotted-aluminum-profiles.html`

Comment: Gotcha. So, if I wanted the links to include both html and non-extension links would I have to put both?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^about-us/t-slotted-aluminum-profiles(?:\.html)?$ https://newdomain.com/profile [L,R=301,NC]` makes `.html` optional

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for all the help! Much appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't this line redirect everything else not specified? `RewriteRule ^ https://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]`